# Isomorphism In Cartesian Closed Category

Tags: category-theory

Is it true that in CCC $( Z^{X+Y} \cong Z^X \times Z^Y )$ ?
I couldn't find any information about it and personally I have troubles with proving it.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: Not every CCC has coproducts, but if it does, then this identity holds.  A category like this (also with an initial object) is known as a bicartesian closed category, so you should be able to find more by searching for that.  I'm not entirely certain if the isomorphism exists just because the coproduct $ X + Y $ exists, if the CCC doesn't have coproducts generally, although I think so.

Comment: @TobyBartels Yes, it still holds if only $X+Y$ exists, and not general colimits, because we can use Yoneda from the left, adjunctions, that products preserve colimits in a CCC, and finally the universal property of the _specific_ coproducts induced by $X+Y$ after taking products.

Comment: This has been asked more than once

Answer (score 1):

This is true, even if just $X+Y$ exists as a coproduct. We follow the proof strategy suggested by Daniël Apol in the comments.
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\begin{array}{llr}
\Hom(A, Z^{X+Y}) & \cong & \text{(adjunction)}\\
\Hom(A \times (X+Y), Z) & \cong & \text{(adjunction)} \\
\Hom(X+Y, Z^A) & \cong & \text{(1)} \\
\Hom(X, Z^A) \times \Hom(Y, Z^A) & \cong & \text{(adjunction)} \\
\Hom(A \times X, Z) \times \Hom(A \times Y, Z) & \cong & \text{(adjunction)} \\
\Hom(A, Z^X) \times \Hom(A, Z^Y) & \cong & \text{(2)} \\
\Hom(A, Z^X \times Z^Y).&&
\end{array}
$$
Here (2) is justified because $\Hom(A, -)$ preserves limits. This is also the justification for (1), but then applied to the opposite category. Alternatively, you can just directly observe that arrows $X+Y \to Z^A$ correspond to pairs of arrows $(X \to Z^A, Y \to Z^A)$.

All of these isomorphisms are natural in $A$. So we have $\Hom(A, Z^{X+Y}) \cong \Hom(A, Z^X \times Z^Y)$ natural in $A$ and conclude that $Z^{X+Y} \cong Z^X \times Z^Y$.